# How can I get the ID of logged in user and use it in my AppServiceProvider file in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

I'm working on my application using Laravel 7. I have used View Composer in my AppServiceProvider to get the count for a number of items in my database table. I have used where clause to get count for a specific logged in user. The problem is that I'm not sure how I can get the ID of currently logged in User and use in my AppServiceProvider. I have tried doing it but I'm getting `Undefined variable: userId` error. Please help. Thanks.

AppServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Project;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $userId = Auth::id();
        
        View::composer('client_panel.layouts.menu', function ($view) {
            $view->with('newprojects', Project::where([
                ['status','=','1'],
                ['created_by','=', $userId]
             ])->count());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of , you cant call outside variable directly inside callback's. So you have to pass using `use`  params. `function ($view)($userId){`

But I don't think `auth user` will available in service provider's So
call inside View composer.

```
  View::composer('client_panel.layouts.menu', function ($view) {
            $view->with('newprojects', Project::where([
                ['status','=','1'],
                ['created_by','=',Auth::user()->id]
             ])->count());
        });
```